# How dropbox knows about my corporate email?

Tags: gmail, dropbox, sniffing

I'm dropbox user.
Today I received some promotional email from them and not to my regular email account but on my corporate-one. I NEVER entered that email address in any of the forms while signing up to their services. So, the question is: how dropbox knows about my corporate email?

My home and corporate email accounts are from gmail.

PS. I never read agreements before using soft, so maybe I missed something here? 
Or maybe dropbox sniffs my traffic or scans file contents on my PC? (omg)

Comment: Are you sure that it is a legitimate Dropbox account and not some kind of spa, or scam? Or somebody just testing whether random email addresses are valid?

Comment: There is NO privacy on the net.

Comment: It should be on `webapps.se`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, Dropbox recently launched a referral program to help its users earn twice as much space as they have by inviting their Friend to dropbox, So probably someone you know invited you using your corporate mail.